# embed flexslider in fields

Tags: javascript

I need to create several nodes of the same type and all have to have an image carousel similar to what flexslider does in Views.
I already deleted the Views example but cannot replicate the behavior in a field in spite that I formatted the field with flexslider full, I just get the images displayed one below the other.

Comment: What version are you using? There was an issue with Fields and alpha 2.

Comment: I enabled flexslider with drush on a clean test site version 7.x-2.0-alpha3. I am getting following warnings in status report: 
    Warning: fopen(sites/all/libraries/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied in _flexslider_requirements_library_installed() (line 212 of /var/www/html/dtest/sites/all/modules/flexslider/flexslider.install).
    Warning: fread() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in _flexslider_requirements_library_installed() (line 213 of /var/www/html/dtest/sites/all/modules/flexslider/flexslider.install).

Comment: Did you follow the installation instructions on the project page? I think the library is missing.

Comment: The library is there.

Comment: It looks like apache doesn't have permission to read sites/all/libraries/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js. Did you check the file permissions? Maybe it's root only?

Comment: @MaartenDeBlock setings perms to 775 recursively on the folder solved the warning, thank you. Image field display is set to flexslider and flexslider_full, but I cannot get a carousel, I get the images stacked one on top of the other.

Comment: Np, I'll make an answer from the comments for other users.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. What version are you using? There was an issue with Fields and alpha 2.
2. Are the libraries downloaded to the correct location? Check the project page for instructions.
3. If the libraries are there, does the webserver user have permission to read the libraries?

Comment: Your answer eliminates the warnings in watchdog, but flexslider is still not functional in the field, images are stacked. Perms on /sites/all set to 775 for all, including flexslider folder and libraries.

Comment: And still no errors in the console of your browser? Did you check 'Reports' -> 'Recent log messages'?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the console of my browser". Yes, there were log messages but they were related to the above mentioned warnings, which were fixed.

Comment: The console in the browsers allows you to see errors and debug your website. More info: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Comment: paste.debian.net/141392 the flexslider function is too big to paste here, please use link. Thank you.